# Add a category column to a pandas dataframe from an existing list of categories

Tags: python, pandas, categories, region

I have a pandas data frame as such:

```
Country_Name    Date    Population  
Afghanistan 7/1/2000    25950816
Afghanistan 7/1/2010    34385068
Albania     7/1/2000    3071856
Albania     7/1/2010    3204284
Algeria     7/1/2000    30533827
Algeria     7/1/2010    35468208
...
```

I also have another dataframe with region data:

```
Region  Country
Asia    Afghanistan
Europe  Albania
Africa  Algeria
Europe  Andorra
Africa  Angola
...
```

I am trying to add a column to my first dataframe that adds the proper region category to each country row.  I don't have code because I'm not sure where to begin.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming df1 is your first dataframe and df2 is your second one, you can merge on the country and perform a left join, you need to rename the country column on df2 first though:

```
df2.rename(columns={'Country':'Country_Name'}, inplace=True)
merged = df1.merge(df2, on='Country_Name', how='left')

# you can either use merged dataframe or assign it to df1:
df1 = merged
```

or you can assign it back to df1 instead of to merged:

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on='Country_Name', how='left')
```

Should give you what you want

Comment: I am successfully renaming the country column to Country_Name column.  I did a print df2.columns to verify.  But the merged command is giving me the KeyError: no item named 'Country_Name'

Comment: Can you confirm that both df1 and df2 have the same column name `Country_Name`

Comment: Ok, I got mixed up with the underscores.  I no longer receive the error and the country columns in both dataframes are "Country Name"   Now, I'd like to add this new region column to the first dataframe

Comment: Well not yet because if I print df1, I still only see my original data, which is country, date, population...I'm not getting that region column to add to df1.

Comment: You can either assign the result to `df1` or use `merged` like `df1 = df1.merge(df2, on='Country_Name', how='left')` or `df1 = merged`

Comment: Gotcha...I used the: df1 = df1.merge(df2, on='Country_Name', how='left') code and it added the column in there.